# Hello World: Finally working but execute command visible on screen

Tags: magento2

I finally have the Hello World module working but the execute string is still visible even after I flushed cache and setup:uprade:

[image]

Everything I know of so far flushed and regenerated:

[image]

Thanks for any help, it's got to be something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your app/code/Pulsestorm/HelloWorldMVVM/Controller/Hello/World.php

```
public function execute()
{        
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();;
    return $page_object;
}
```

Replace

```
public function execute()
{        
    $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();;
    return $page_object;
}
```

This is caused var_dump(**METHOD**);
Flush cache and try it , Hope this helps.